# A const member function can not deduce parameter type

Tags: c++

Here is the code:

```
vector<ClientInfo*> OpenRABiz::GetHumans() const {
    vector<ClientInfo*> vec;
    for (auto &c : clients) {
        if (!c.isbot) {
            vec.push_back(&c);
        }
    }
    return vec; // RVO - return value optimization
}
```

In visual c++ 2019, compiler indate it:

```
error C2664: 'void std::vector<ClientInfo *,std::allocator<ClientInfo *>>::push_back(_Ty &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const ClientInfo *' to 'const _Ty &'
```

The error message: "

> const _Ty&" means the c++ template can't deduce the right parameters

.

When I take the `const` keyword, it compiles successfully.

```
vector<ClientInfo*> OpenRABiz::GetHumans()
```

Why?

Comment: RVO from local variable is NRVO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `clients` is likely a vector of `ClientInfo`, so in a `const`-qualified member-functions, the type of `client` (in the loop) is `const ClientInfo&`. When you take the address `&client`, you get a `const ClientInfo*`, which cannot be converted to a `ClientInfo*`.

When you remove the `const`-qualifier, everything works fine because `client` is then `ClientInfo&`.

To fix the issue, change the return-type of the function and declaration of `vec` to `std::vector<const ClientInfo*>`.